# Google Plus integration fails on Android with "internal error" toast

Tags: android, google-plus

I have followed the instructions in the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started#step_4_initialize_the_googleapiclient) for the Google Plus sample app and I'm receiving the error message "An internal error has occured" I have tried both registering and regenerating a debug keystore as well as generating and recreating a release keystore. I have registered all the keystores' SHA1 certificate fingerprints into my google console and the error message still persists. I have also made sure that the  package names are correct and I have gone through the tutorial several times. Is there any other reason why the "internal error" message may come up?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things! Check your logcat output - in particularly look for anything containing GLS. You can turn on more verbose logging with:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.GooglePlusPlatform VERBOSE
```

Classic errors are:
1. Different packagename/signing key used in APK than on the console
2. Bad scopes requested (usually when using GoogleAuthUtil rather than PlusClient, but can happen with either)
3. Bad App Activity URLs being requested.

In general, check each string looks exactly as it should in the documentation, and check the log for hints.